# Find Bluetooth Le Gatt (Motion UUID) to receive motion sensor data

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am new to Bluetooth Low Energy GATT. Now I have a motion sensor with the RN4020 microchip bluetooth module.

I'm having issues on receiving data from my motion sensor.

Currently I am able to scan my motion sensor with my android apps, but it shows **Unknown Services and Unknown Characteristics**.

I am pleased to ask that How can I receive my motion sensor data in between BLE device to my android apps?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Unknown Services and Unknown Characteristics means that they are using un-assigned UUID or vendor specific IDs.
Supposedly the sensor data should have been exposed in some characteristic with notification or readable, and you only need to subscribe the notification or read the value accordingly.